# Can’t collect data from Firestore into Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I successfully sent data to Firestore (collection:Food), but I couldn't collect data from Firestore (collection:Food). I even added try/catch and set breakpoints, but I couldn't gain more information other than the following error.

Error:

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings.toString()

Code (collect data from Firestore) error:

```
// MainActivity.java 
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("Food")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            ArrayList<CloudFood> arrayfood = new ArrayList<>();

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String id = document.getId();
                String foodName = document.getString("food_name");
                int per = document.getLong("per").intValue();
                double calorie = document.getDouble("calorie");
                double carbon = document.getDouble("carbon");
                double protein = document.getDouble("protein");
                double fat = document.getDouble("fat");

                CloudFood foodItem = new CloudFood(id, foodName, per, calorie, carbon, protein, fat);
                arrayfood.add(foodItem);
            }
        } else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    });
```

**CloudFood.java**

```
package com.example.dietmanagement;

public class CloudFood {
    private String id;
    private String foodName;
    private int per;
    private double calorie;
    private double carbon;
    private double protein;
    private double fat;

    // Constructor
    public CloudFood(String id, String foodName, int per, double calorie, double carbon, double protein, double fat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.per = per;
        this.calorie = calorie;
        this.carbon = carbon;
        this.protein = protein;
        this.fat = fat;
    }

    // Getters and setters
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFoodName() {
        return foodName;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
    }

    public int getPer() {
        return per;
    }

    public void setPer(int per) {
        this.per = per;
    }

    public double getCalorie() {
        return calorie;
    }

    public void setCalorie(double calorie) {
        this.calorie = calorie;
    }

    public double getCarbon() {
        return carbon;
    }

    public void setCarbon(double carbon) {
        this.carbon = carbon;
    }

    public double getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }

    public void setProtein(double protein) {
        this.protein = protein;
    }

    public double getFat() {
        return fat;
    }

    public void setFat(double fat) {
        this.fat = fat;
    }
}
```

Code(send data to Firestore) works successfully:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Map<String, Object> db_user = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    db_user.put("food_name", food);
    db_user.put("per", per);
    db_user.put("calorie", cal);
    db_user.put("carbon", car);
    db_user.put("protein", pro);
    db_user.put("fat", fat);
    db.collection("Food").document(food + "_"+adInfo.getId()).set(db_user).
            addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                }
            });
```

**Firestore, collection:Food**

[image: Firestore]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace so we know which line(s) of your code are leading to the exception?

Comment: According to the Firebase Console screenshot above, you have 2 documents in `Food` with IDs `3` and `food`.  Do both documents have a `food_name` value?

Comment: Does the `arrayfood` contain any data by the end of the loop? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @Greg Fenton Appreciate the comments. Yes, both documents have food_name value. I was so stupid that I didn't put number data into "per", "calorie" of the document' ID = "food".

Comment: @AlexMamo 
Appreciate your comment. No, arrayfood didn't contain any data. I found that I had a problem with "int per = document.getLong("per").intValue();" and app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 issues.

**1. I contained String type of numbers into "per", "calorie",etc as I pasted at the question.**

And I found an error in the following codes.

```
int per = document.getLong("per").intValue();
double calorie = document.getDouble("calorie");
double carbon = document.getDouble("carbon");
double protein = document.getDouble("protein");
double fat = document.getDouble("fat");
CloudFood foodItem = new CloudFood(id, foodName, per, calorie, carbon, protein, fat);
```

I changed to

```
String per = document.getString("per");
String calorie = document.getString("calorie");
String carbon = document.getString("carbon");
String protein = document.getString("protein");
String fat = document.getString("fat");
CloudFood foodItem = new CloudFood(id, foodName, Integer.parseInt(per), Double.parseDouble(calorie),
Double.parseDouble(carbon), Double.parseDouble(protein), Double.parseDouble(fat));
```

Second issue was too personal, but the another document's "per", "calorie" were String type of texts, so I had an error when I tried to convert from String to Integer or Double. Therefore, I fixed data to String type of numbers.